# Calculate the number of elements of an array that are not divisors of each element

Tags: java, algorithm, performance, time-complexity, space-complexity

I try to understand a solution to a problem from the Codility. The problem asks to calculate the number of elements of an array that are not divisors of each element. The full description is provided below,

```
You are given a non-empty zero-indexed array A consisting of N integers.
    For each number A[i] such that 0 ≤ i < N, we want to count the number of elements of the array that are not the divisors of A[i]. We say that these elements are non-divisors.
    For example, consider integer N = 5 and array A such that:
        A[0] = 3
        A[1] = 1
        A[2] = 2
        A[3] = 3
        A[4] = 6
    For the following elements:
    A[0] = 3, the non-divisors are: 2, 6,
    A[1] = 1, the non-divisors are: 3, 2, 3, 6,
    A[2] = 2, the non-divisors are: 3, 3, 6,
    A[3] = 3, the non-divisors are: 2, 6,
    A[6] = 6, there aren't any non-divisors.
    Write a function:
    class Solution { public int[] solution(int[] A); }
    that, given a non-empty zero-indexed array A consisting of N integers, returns a sequence of integers representing the amount of non-divisors.
    The sequence should be returned as:
    a structure Results (in C), or
    a vector of integers (in C++), or
    a record Results (in Pascal), or
    an array of integers (in any other programming language).
    For example, given:
        A[0] = 3
        A[1] = 1
        A[2] = 2
        A[3] = 3
        A[4] = 6
    the function should return [2, 4, 3, 2, 0], as explained above.
    Assume that:
    N is an integer within the range [1..50,000];
    each element of array A is an integer within the range [1..2 * N].
    Complexity:
    expected worst-case time complexity is O(N*log(N));
    expected worst-case space complexity is O(N), beyond input storage (not counting the storage required for input arguments).
    Elements of input arrays can be modified.
```

I have a solution too.

```
// int[] A = {3, 1, 2, 3, 6};
public static int[] solution(int[] A) {

    int[][] D = new int[2 * A.length + 1][2];
    int[] res = new int[A.length];      

        //----- 
        // 0 1 
        // 0 0 
        // 1 -1 
        // 1 -1 
        // 2 -1 
        // 0 0 
        // 0 0 
        // 1 -1 
        // 0 0 
        // 0 0 
        // 0 0 
        // 0 0
        //-----

    for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
        // D[A[i]][0]++;

        D[A[i]][0] = D[A[i]][0] + 1;
        D[A[i]][1] = -1;
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++){

        if(D[A[i]][1]==-1){

            D[A[i]][1]=0;

            for (int j = 1; j*j <= A[i]; j++) {

                if(A[i] % j == 0) {

                    // D[A[i]][1] = D[A[i]][1] + D[j][0];
                    D[A[i]][1] += D[j][0];

                    if (A[i]/j != j){
                        D[A[i]][1]+= D[A[i]/j][0];
                    }
                }                   
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
        res[i] = A.length - D[A[i]][1]; 
    }

    return res;
}
```

As I try to follow closely, I kind of lose the track of what is going on inside the for loop,

```
            for (int j = 1; j*j <= A[i]; j++) {

                if(A[i] % j == 0) {

                    // D[A[i]][1] = D[A[i]][1] + D[j][0];
                    D[A[i]][1] += D[j][0];

                    if (A[i]/j != j){
                        D[A[i]][1]+= D[A[i]/j][0];
                    }
                }                   
            }
```

For example, why do we need to check conditions like `j*j <= A[i]` and what's for the `if(A[i] % j == 0)`. I need an explanation of the algorithm they deployed to solve the question.

I'm not being lazy as I already get a solution and not trying. Indeed, I spend good time and help is needed now. The problem hardness is listed as `RESPECTABLE` in the website.

Comment: The `j*j <= A[i]` and `if(A[i] % j == 0)` conditions are basically checks for divisors: if you have an int `n` and you don't know if it's prime you can search for divisors from `2` to `sqrt(n)` in order to minimize iterations. Interesting algorithm though, I'm going to spend some time trying to figure it out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `D` data structure/matrix is such that the `0th` column and `jth` row counts the number of times `j` occurs in the array `A`.  In other words `D[A[j]][0]` is the number of times the value of `A[j]` is in the array.

After the loops, the `1st` column and `kth` row count the number of elements in the array which divide `A[k]`.  In other words `D[A[k]][1]` is the number of divisors of `A[k]` in the array.

At the end the result `r[j]` is just `r[j] = (A.length) - D[A[j]][1]`.  Since we want the number of elements which are NOT divisors.

Why do the loops work?

Well if `A[i] % j == 0` then what we would want to do is count the number of times `j` appears in `A` and then add that to `D[A[i]][1]`.  That's why you have the line `D[A[i]][1] += D[j][0];` .  Furthermore `A[i]/j` will also be a different factor (except if `A[i] = j`).

The math part comes in proving that the set { A, B | A * B = N & A < sqrt(N) } = {the set of divisors of N}.  In other words you have to prove that all divisors are covered  (this should be easy but I am too tired to think of the proof now and this is Stack overflow).

Comment: This is very helpful. Thank you so much.